# Python for i in arr : arr.remove(i) function

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2F6q.png)

I was creating 'sieve of eratosthenes' in python and i found using 'remove' while operating 'for' loop removes only odd numbers (or even index element).

I thought it would remove all things in 'arr' list, removing its elements itself.

Can Anyone explain this?

Here is the Code

```
arr = list(range(1, 11))
for i in arr:
    arr.remove(i)
print(arr)
```

p.s. Sorry for bad gramma.

Comment: As a note to those who voted to close as dup, this case is a bit different from the usual cases, in that they really wanted to empty the ENTIRE list, not just a few elements.

Comment: @TimRoberts Does that matter? The question is the same.

Comment: But a different answer is needed.

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't think so. Not really. Unless you imagine an additional question that's not actually there ("How can I achieve what I want?").

Comment: @TimRoberts I mean, even your own "answer" only "answers" with *"The internal pointers get all screwed up"* (the rest is fluff that doesn't address the question). You can say the exact same thing at the other questions (partly because it's so vague/vacuous).

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify a list while you are iterating it.  The internal pointers get all screwed up.  In this case, to clear a list without just assigning a new object, you can do:

```
arr[:] = []
```

Comment: I suppose I should say "should not" when I post this advice, which happens about twice a week.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I didn't know what happpens if I modify iterating list.

By the way, can I use


`arr = []`


this code to clear the list? 
Is there anything different using slicer?

Comment: There is a big difference, but it only matters in some circumstances.  Using the slice notation modifies the existing list object.  Using the assignment creates a NEW list object and discards the old one.  If, for example, `arr` was a parameter in a function, then using the assignment means you are now working with a different list object.  Your changes will not be seen by the caller.  Whether that's good or bad depends on your design.